# How to connect to database php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a7796367_Bubelz", "password"); or die("Couldn't connect to SQL server.");
    mysql_select_db("a7796367_Bubelz"); or die("Couldn't select DB.");
?>​
```

I can't connect to my database. I'm using 000webhost.com

When I open it, it shows me this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in    
/home/a7796367/public_html/bubelz/connect.inc.php on line 2
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Simply remove `;` before `or`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove ; in first line of code:

```
mysql_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a7796367_Bubelz", "password"); <---
```

Answer (score 1):

try this you have syntax error and you have to use **mysqli** insted becuse **mysql**   Officially deprecated

```
mysql_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a7796367_Bubelz", "password") or die("Couldn't connect to SQL server.");
mysql_select_db("a7796367_Bubelz") or die("Couldn't select DB.");


mysqli

$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db') ;
```

Comment: Sometimes I also forget this syntactical typo error.. Thanks @Osama Jetawe.

Comment: I dont have enough permissions to mark your answer., Are you asking me or @Nicholas Bastarache

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot write `OR` like this.

```
mysql_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a7796367_Bubelz", "password"); 
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL server.");
```

You can use as follows

```
if(!mysql_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a7796367_Bubelz", "password")){ 
    die("Couldn't connect to SQL server.");
}
```